# Formdata isnt working in Apex

Tags: apex, api

I was trying to Post a document to an api using LWC and ran into a cors issue and moved the code to Apex. I'm attaching a picture of the postman that shows what it looks like.

[image: Postman picture]

So looking up solutions I found that I would need a boundary and this is what it looks like.

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.boldsign.com/v1/template/create');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');
        req.setHeader('X-API-KEY', API_KEY);
    
        Property__c prop = [Select Name from Property__c where id =:id];

        String body = '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Title\"\r\n\r\n'+prop.Name+' Lease Agreement';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';

        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][Name]\"\r\n\r\n'+'Tenant';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][Index]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '1';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][DefaultSignerName]\"\r\n\r\n'+ tenantName;
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][DefaultSignerEmail]\"\r\n\r\n'+ tenantEmail;
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][Type]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'Initial';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][PageNumber]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '1';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '14';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '16';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '40';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '30';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][0][IsRequired]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'True';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][Type]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'Initial';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][PageNumber]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '2';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][X]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '14';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Y]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '16';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Width]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '40';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Height]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '30';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][1][IsRequired]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'True';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';

        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][Type]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'Signature';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][PageNumber]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '2';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][X]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '320';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Y]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '200';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Width]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '176';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Height]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '28';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][FormFields][2][IsRequired]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'True';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';

        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][SignerOrder]\"\r\n\r\n'+ '1';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"Roles[0][SignerType]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'Signer';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"DocumentInfo[0][Title]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'Lease Agreement';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"DocumentInfo[0][Language]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'English';
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
        body += 'name=\"DocumentInfo[0][Description]\"\r\n\r\n'+ 'English Languages'; 
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';

        PageReference pdf = new pagereference('/apex/renderAsPdf');
        Blob file;
        try {
            file = pdf.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            file = Blob.valueOf('data');
            system.debug(e);
        }
        body += 'name=\"Files\" filename=\"[PROXY]\"\r\n\r\n'+ file;
        body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--';

        req.setBody(body);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());

        
        
        return res.getStatusCode()+'::'+res.getBody();
```

But when I do it this way I get an error 500 and no errors at all even when I omit required fields. On the other hand when I comment out the

`req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');`

line then I get errors of missing items again but it doesn't register any of the fields I've tried to enter.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the newline after the form value and before the next boundary marker.

For example:

```
    body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
    body += 'name=\"Roles[0][Name]\"\r\n\r\n'+'Tenant';
```

Should be:

```
    body += '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
    body += 'name=\"Roles[0][Name]\"\r\n\r\n'+'Tenant\r\n'; // Added this here
```